# Why "corruption on heap" error message while freeing unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, free, unmanaged

I have a code snippet in my C# project as follows:

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE findTemplate = new CK_ATTRIBUTE();                                                 

findTemplate.type = CKAT_USER_NAME;
findTemplate.pValue = new IntPtr();
findTemplate.pValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MAX_USERID_LENGTH);
Marshal.Copy(sUserName, 0, findTemplate.pValue, MAX_USERID_LENGTH);
findTemplate.ulValueLen = MAX_USERID_LENGTH;

IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(findTemplate, ptr, false);

/*Call pinvoke function here which modifies ptr*/

Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, findTemplate);

byte[] userIdBytes = new byte[findTemplate.ulValueLen];

Marshal.Copy(findTemplate.pValue, userIdBytes, 0, (int) findTemplate.ulValueLen);
adminKeyName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(userIdBytes);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(findTemplate.pValue); //this causes error                         
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr); //this does not
```

CK_ATTRIBUTE is a structure with sequential layout and with members type (String) pValue (IntPtr) and ulvaluelen (int)

Why do I get "corruption on heap" error message for the first freeing?

The function I am pinvoking is defined as follows:

```
[DllImport("sduserSES.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            static extern uint C_GetAttributeValue(uint hSession,   /* the session's handle */
                                                  uint hObject,    /* the object's handle */
                                                  IntPtr pTemplate,  /* specifies attributes, gets values */
                                                  uint ulCount     /* attributes in template */
                                                  );
```

Comment: Your "`/*Call pinvoke function here which modifies ptr*/`" is likely where your problem lies. Please show the header file definition of the function and your P/Invoke implementation of it. By default P/Invoke uses `CallingConvention.StdCall` but it is very possible that your code should be `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: The odds that FreeHGlobal() can work properly on a modified pointer are zilch.  Pretty evident from your questions that you are pinvoking pretty badly behaving native code.  If this actually works okay from a native program then it is high time that you consider writing a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: Since .NET 4.5.1 you can write `Marshal.SizeOf<CK_ATTRIBUTE>()` instead of `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE))`.

Comment: @HansPassant it works okay from a native program. I prefer pinvoke to a c++/cli wrapper. I was thinking of calling a special free function that I defined on the native side (accepting memory to be deleted) and freeing the memory from the native side.